# Where does dmesg get kernel messages and user space messages?

Tags: linux, debian, logs, dmesg

`dmesg` is said to examine or control the kernel ring buffer. But it has option `--kernel` and `--userspace`.

Does `dmesg` get kernel messages from the kernel ring buffer?

Does the kernel ring buffer store only messages generated by the kernel, not those by processes?

Where does `dmesg` get user space messages?

Do user space messages include those messages generated by all the processes, for example, by cron?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does `dmesg` get kernel messages from the kernel ring buffer?

Yes, as described in [`man dmesg`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dmesg.1.html):

> `dmesg` is used to examine or control the kernel ring buffer.

> Does the kernel ring buffer store only messages generated by the kernel, not those by processes?

No, processes can add messages to the kernel ring buffer, by writing to `/dev/kmsg`.

> Where does `dmesg` get user space messages?

From the kernel ring buffer, using either `/dev/kmsg` or [the `syslog` system call](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syslog.2.html) (not to be confused with [the `syslog` system logger](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/syslog.3.html) and associated services). Messages are distinguished by their “facility”; kernel messages use the `kern` facility, user messages the `user`, `mail`, `daemon` etc. facilities (see `dmesg --help` for a list of supported facilities).

> Do user space messages include those messages generated by all the processes, for example, by cron?

No, only those explicitly added to the kernel ring buffer.

`syslog` dæmons can typically *read* from the kernel ring buffer on Linux, but that’s the only connection. I’m not aware of anything that *writes* to the buffer apart from the kernel (which doesn’t need a device to do so), and systemd (which will write to the kernel buffer if it can’t write to its journal or to `syslog`).

Comment: Thanks. Is /dev/kmsg the device file for the kernel ring buffer?  Does dmesg get all the messages (both kernel and user space ones) from /dev/kmsg?  /dev/kmsg is named as if to be used by the kernel only, so what processes would like to add messages to the kernel ring buffer (by writing to /dev/kmsg)?

Comment: Is the kernel ring buffer and /dev/kmsg such a place which the syslog daemon does not write to and read from?  Is the kernel ring buffer and /dev/kmsg unrelated to the syslog daemon?

Comment: Also see my previous question (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/643119/in-syslog-or-rsyslog-are-ring-buffer-queue-of-message-and-write-buffer-the-sa) and thanks in advance.

Comment: See the updated answer.

Comment: /dev/kmsg is a character device. Does being a character device mean it doesn't hold data written to it, and any  read will only read data written after the read operation is issued, not data written beforehand?

Comment: A device node, whether it’s a character device or a block device, only provides access to a driver; it doesn’t store any data itself. `/dev/kmsg` provides access to the ring buffer, which exists independently of `/dev/kmsg`.

Comment: Is it up to a driver whether to store data?

Comment: "syslog dæmons can typically read from the kernel ring buffer on Linux, but that’s the only connection". What is "the only connection", and what are the other coonections which are not possible?

Comment: Yes, what happens to data written to devices is up to the driver. The only connection is that syslog dæmons can read from the buffer. Other possible connections I can think of are the ability to write to the buffer and control the console logging level, but one could imagine many more.

Comment: Do you mean that a process normally doesn't write to the kernel ring buffer, and a process other than dmesg normally doesn't read from the kernel ring buffer?

Comment: Is the kernel ring buffer considered the logging facility owned by the kernel, or is it considered as a "centralized logging facility" used by both the kernel and processes?

Comment: It’s the kernel ring buffer, owned by the kernel. It’s not intended to be a central logging facility; it’s far too small for that. I listed the processes other than `dmesg` that read from it in my answer; I’m not sure how else to list them.

Comment: How does syslog dæmons typically read from the kernel ring buffer on Linux? By klogd? Not by /dev/log?

Comment: I’m not sure why klogd or `/dev/log` suddenly make an appearance... System logging dæmons read from the kernel ring buffer in the same way `dmesg` does (see the description in the answer).

Comment: So sorry for miscommunication. klogd is a daemon that reads the messages from /proc/kmsg or /dev/kmsg (or calls sys_syslog, if /proc is not mounted) and sends them to syslogd(8), or to the console (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/643350). So I guess syslogd or rsyslogd reads the ring buffer indirectly via klogd. But I didn't find it running on Ubuntu. So I am not sure.

Comment: Yes, I’m familiar with klogd, but it hasn’t been in common use for nearly a decade. rsyslogd and systemd’s journal read directly from `/dev/kmsg`.

Comment: rsyslogd is a server listening passively. Is it a client which actively sends read requests to /dev/kmsg?

Comment: If it’s configured to do so, yes. See `imklog` in `man rsyslog.conf`.